# Elasticsearch multiple aggregations from array

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

How can I dynamically combine multiple aggregations in one query dynamically?

I know to do it "hard-coded":

```
request.Aggregations = new TermsAggregation("agg_field1") {
    Field = "field1"
}
&& new TermsAggregation("agg_field2") {
    Field = "field2"
};
```

But since I use an array containing the fields I need something like the following. But I'm getting an compiler error because 'AggregationDictionary' and 'TermsAggregation' cannot be combined by the operator '&=':

```
string[] Fields = new[]{ "field1", "field2" }
foreach (string sField in Fields)
{
    request.Aggregations &= new TermsAggregation("agg_" + sField)
    {
        Field = sField
    };
}
```

I have article data with fields like "product", "brand", "modell".
For this fields I want to get each distinct value by aggregation. It's for showing three comboboxes with the possible values for each field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few different ways in which you could build up a collection of aggregations. The nearest to what you're trying to do would be

```
var request = new SearchRequest<object>();

string[] Fields = new[] { "field1", "field2" };
AggregationBase aggregations = null;  
foreach (string sField in Fields)
{
    var termsAggregation = new TermsAggregation("agg_" + sField)
    {
        Field = sField
    };

    if (aggregations == null)
    {
        aggregations = termsAggregation;
    }
    else
    {
        aggregations &= termsAggregation;
    }
}

request.Aggregations = aggregations;

client.Search<object>(request);
```

which builds the following query

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "agg_field1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "field1"
      }
    },
    "agg_field2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "field2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Russ cam, Please help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453469/how-to-create-dynamic-nested-aggregations-query-in-elastic-search-net-based-on-m