# How to create dynamic nested aggregations query in elastic search.net based on multiple fields

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, aggregate

How to create dynamic nested aggregations query in Elastic search.net based on multiple fields.

**These are my fields.**

1. keyword 1
2. keyword 2
3. keyword 3

**This is my static query.**

```
ISearchResponse<T> response = client.Search<T>
                (
                    s => s
                    .Index(indexName)
                    .Type(docType)
                    .Size(0)
                    .RequestConfiguration(r => r.DisableDirectStreaming())
                    .Aggregations
                    (
                        a => a.Terms("result_by_keyword_1", t => t.Field("keyword 1").Missing("N/A").Size(10000)
                        .Aggregations
                        (
                            ag => ag.Terms("result_by_keyword_2", tg => tg.Field("keyword 2").Missing("N/A").Size(10000)
                            .Aggregations
                            (
                                agf => agf.Terms("result_by_keyword_3", tfg => tfg.Field("keyword 3").Missing("N/A").Size(10000))
                            ))
                        ))
                    )
                 );
```

**I need to access data like this:**

```
foreach (var bucket in response.Aggs.Terms("result_by_keyword_1").Buckets)
            {
                foreach (var innerBucket in bucket.Terms("result_by_keyword_2").Buckets)
                {
                    foreach (var innerBucket1 in innerBucket.Terms("result_by_keyword_3").Buckets)
                    {
                        AggregateData aggData = new AggregateData();
                        aggData.keyword1= bucket.Key;
                        aggData.keyword2= innerBucket.Key;
                        aggData.keyword3= innerBucket1.Key;
                        aggData.recordcount = innerBucket1.DocCount;
                        results.Add(aggData);
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Problems are :**
Actually I want to create a dynamic query based on multiple fields. here I have 3 fields but it may more than 3 fields.so based on fields count I want to nested aggeration in elastic search in .net.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So whats the actual problem?

Comment: @MichaelRandall, Actually I want to create a dynamic query based on multiple fields. here I have 3 fields but it may more than 3 fields.so based on fields count I want to nested aggeration in elastic search in .net.